# Padding is not showing in chrome but showing in firefox

Tags: html, css, wordpress, gravity

I am adding padding on select box option. But the padding is showing only on Firefox but now showing on chrome i try plenty of things but not working for me so anyone tell me what to do to add padding on chrome This is the [Link](http://logodesign.inkgility.com/) at bottom you can see the dropdown

This is the code which i am using

```
select#input_1_1 option {
    padding: 10px 30px !important;
}
```

Comment: Post your code here, not a link to your website.

Comment: Okay thanks did that please check

Answer (score 2):

Firefox allows giving CSS `padding` to `select` and `option` tags, but Chrome doesn't. Period.

Comment: @jayantrawat Sorry, my mistake. Check the updated answer.

Comment: So any suggestion for this

Comment: @jayantrawat Instead you can use an excellent plugin called [Select2](https://select2.github.io).

Comment: @jayantrawat Is that plugin okay for you?

Comment: Not so because this is the gravity form select option

Comment: Isn't any way to do this with css

Comment: Is it possible with jquery?

Comment: @jayantrawat Yes, use Select2 as suggested in an earlier comment.